# Understanding step in proof of GAN algorithm convergence, involving convexity

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, generative-models, convex

I am reading the original paper on GANs, https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661. The proof of proposition 2, on the convergence of the gradient descent algorithm reads

> Consider $V(G, D) = U(p_g, D)$ as a function of $p_g$ as done in the above criterion. Note
> that $U(p_g, D)$ is convex in $p_g$ ...

here (I think) $V(G,D) = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{\text{data}(x)}} [\log D(x)] + \mathbb{E}_{z \sim p_z(z)}[\log(1 − D(G(z)))]$ is the value function of the GAN, and the 'above criterion' is that $p_g$ is updated so that the value function decreases (for the generator). Details are in the paper, it is not long.

**What does it mean for $U$ to be convex in $p_g$?** $U$ is a function of a distribution, and I can't interpret what convexity means in this context, even making assumptions on what $p_g$ is (e.g Gaussian)

Answer (score 1):

> **What does it mean for $U$ to be convex in $p_g$?** $U$ is a function of a distribution, and I can't interpret what convexity means in this
> context, even making assumptions on what $p_g$ is (e.g Gaussian)

If you recall the definition of convexity, it doesn't assume that function domain is finite-dimensional, only it is a convex subset of a linear space.

Distribution functions on $A$ are a subset of integrable functions on $A$, which is a linear space. It is in fact convex subset, just check the convexity property of $\int_A p(x) dx = 1$.

Because of that, it makes sense to say that some function of distributions on $A$ is convex.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the definition. I am happy that distribution functions are a convex subset. Am I right in thinking that $U$ is in fact linear in $p_g$, from which convexity follows (i.e, there's always equality in the convexity statement)?

Comment: Yes, expectation is linear operator w.r.t. density function.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $V$ is loss and it's actually Expectation.

And for Expectation we know $E(aX + b) = aE(X) + b$

Thus, by definition of convexity RHS ans LHS will be same.